Laravel 10: dispatchSync method throws an exception: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]]
Upon dispatching job synchronously, it throws an exception:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider

This exception appears only if job fails.
Removing "Queueable" trait fixes this issue, but I need to run this job both synchronously and in the queue.
In previous Laravel versions it worked.
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private array $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct( array $data = [] )
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        // ...
        $this->fail();
    }
}

--
SomeJob::dispatch($data); // OK
SomeJob::dispatchSync($data) // Exception :((


Hello Alexander. This issue is strange, I've created a test job on a Laravel 10 project which has the same code as yours, and tried dispatching within the queue and synchronously, but I was unable to reproduce the issue. Do you by any chance have custom service providers? if yes please update the question with their contents. Also, please update the question and include the code of your AppServiceProvider class.

Thanks @eyad-bereh.
I've checked my AppServiceProvider class and the reason was there.

You're welcome @Alexander, I'm glad my comment was helpful

I've figured out it.
The reason is the following line in the AppServiceProvider class, boot method:
Queue::failing([ AppServiceProvider::class, 'handleFailedJob' ]);

Which refers to this method:
public static function handleFailedJob(JobFailed $event)
{
    // ..
}

